# Counting even digits of a NaturalNumber

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write a method (specifically using recursion) that would return the number of even digits in a natural number.  I'd like to do so with a return type of NaturalNumber in order to gain more familiarity with it.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
//private static NaturalNumber countEvenDigits(NaturalNumber num)

//initalize a NaturalNumber--count--to zero

//while loop with condition that the num is not 0

//initialize a NaturalNumber--k--to num.divideBy10 so that it is equal to the last digit in the natural number

//if statement-- k mod 2 is equal to 0

//increment the NaturalNumber count

//end if statement

//call this function recursively

//end while statement

//return count
```

However my current implementation just returns 0, what am I thinking about in a wrong way?

Comment: NaturalNumber is not a standard Java class. I'd do it using int to start with.

Comment: Just use %10 to get last digit and then check if it's even then return 1+f(num/10). Otherwise return f(num/10)

Comment: needs to be mod 10, not divide by 10 if you want to get the last digit. 123 / 10 = 12, 123 % 10 = 3

Comment: I understand that int would be easier, but I'd like to do NaturalNumber for exercise purposes

Comment: I'm returning a Natural Number so "+1" isn't a thing that would work I believe

Comment: With NaturalNumbers using the method .divideBy10 returns the last digit.

Answer (score 0):

First if all, you posted this in Java, so I guess natural number is Integer (or int primitive)

Then your function needs to have a check in the beginning if the function call "end requirement" is fulfilled (number != 0).

If your number is != 0, you actually do the check if it is even or odd. After this check, you need to remember that (count++) and add the return value of the recursive method call onto your count, but with the last digit removed, because you checked that in this call already. (count += countEvenDigits(naturalNumber/10)). This should call itself as long as there are more digits and finally, it will get into the initial if() that exits.

```
/** http://stackoverflow.com/q/36085564/6077352 */
public class NaturalNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int naturalNumber = 123456789;
        System.out.println(countEvenDigits(naturalNumber));
    }
    private static int countEvenDigits(int naturalNumber) {
        int count = 0;
        if (naturalNumber != 0) {
            if (naturalNumber % 2 == 0) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            count = count + countEvenDigits(naturalNumber / 10);
        }
        return count;
}   }
```

Example output:

> 4